# How do I calculate the electric field of a dipole after passing through a collecting lens with a given NA?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-fields, lenses, dipole

How can I make the (far field) electric field of a dipole dependent on the numerical aperture of a collection lense it is passing through?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, an index of refraction has no effect on a static electric field.  If you know the dielectric constant for the glass, it might be possible to calculate a surface charge density, but this would be quite complex in a dipole field.